# Format string for zero padding decimal with sign in front?

Tags: formatting, common-lisp

Is there a format string for zero padding a decimal with the sign in front?

```
(format nil ? 5) => "+0005"
(format nil ? -5) => "-0005"
```

The closest I found was

```
(format nil "~4,'0@d" 5) => "00+5"
(format nil "~4,'0@d" -5) => "00-5"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a draft of a custom printer function:

```
(defun signed-padding (stream data colonp atsignp &optional (padding 0))
  (declare (ignore colonp atsignp))
  (format stream "~:[+~;-~]~v,'0d" (minusp data) padding (abs data)))
```

...and an example:

```
(values
 (format nil "~v/signed-padding/" 20 330)
 (format nil "~5/signed-padding/" -4))

"+00000000000000000330"
"-00004"
```

You could probably add more checks and options.